# Changing to spherical coordinates to evaluate the integral

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

$$\iiint_D  \,dz\,dy\,dx$$

where the region $D$ is defined as followed:

$$0<z<\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$$
$$0<y<\sqrt{9-x^2}$$ $$0<x<3$$

I got the corresponding spherical coordinates for $D$:

$$0<\rho<3$$$$0<\theta<\pi/2$$
$$0<\phi<\pi/2$$
 where $\theta$ is the angle between $x$ and $y$, $\phi$is the angle between $z$ and $xy$ plane.

Have I correctly calculated this region of integration in polar coordinates?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: That looks like a good start on this integral.  Do you have a question?

Comment: I like to know if I got the region of integration right?

Comment: You got the same bounds I did, so its probably right. Good luck with the rest of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First cartesian condition: upper half-sphere(center=$O$, radius=3).

Second cartesian condition:  half-cilynder(axis=$Z$, radius=3). As sphere $\subset$ cilynder, only the $0<y$ inequality is relevant.

Third cartesian condition: slice. As sphere $\subset$ ($x<3$) only the $0<x$ inequality is relevant.

Bottom line: you are cutting the sphere by the three positive half-spaces $x>0$, $y>0$, $z>0$.